# my contacts app stops when i try to write or update to my SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

my app seems to stop everytime i try to add new contacts or update existing ones

my app is simple , i make the user enter the data of his contacts (firstname, lastname,mobile...etc) and he saves it to a database then he can see it in the main list view (notdone yet :) ) and then he can choose which contact to be displayed inorder to edit or delete him

can you help me with those crashes please??

below is the database class

```
public class DBcreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
/*
 * this class is responsible for all the database manipulation and
 * requirements it is called inside other classes for implementation
 */
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts";// NAME OF THE
                                                        // DATABASE//
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contactsdisplay";// NAME OF THE
                                                                // TABLE
                                                                // INSIDE OF
                                                                // IT//
// THE DATA INSIDE THE TABLE//
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "first name";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "last name";
public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
// VERSION OF THE DATABASE//
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// create database//
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "Create table"
        + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID
        + "integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_FNAME + "TEXT"
        + KEY_LNAME + "TEXT" + KEY_MOBILE + "TEXT" + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT);";

public DBcreator(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);// this orders the code to create the
                                // database//

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db,
        int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // drop old version and use the new one//
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public long add(String fname, String lname, String mob, String address) {
    // getting the database and editing in it//
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // insert what the user had entered in the database//
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
    cv.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
    cv.put(KEY_MOBILE, mob);
    cv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    // db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public void savechanges(String fname, String lname, String mob,
        String address) {
    // change the existing data of the contact by lookup then replace//
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] array = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME,
            KEY_MOBILE, KEY_ADDRESS };
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, array, fname, null, null, null,
            null);
    // we need to loop inside the database to find the existing values and
    // replace them//
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        int firstname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int lastname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int mobile = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int address2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        if (c.getString(firstname).equals(fname)) {
            ContentValues changes = new ContentValues();
            changes.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
            changes.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
            changes.put(KEY_MOBILE, mob);
            changes.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
            db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, changes, KEY_FNAME + "=" + fname,
                    null);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void deletecontact(String fnamedelete) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_FNAME + "=" + fnamedelete, null);
}

public String[] queryall() {
    String[] FirstNames = new String[] { KEY_FNAME };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cfname = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, FirstNames, null, null, null,
            null, null);// to see all contacts//
    int GetTheName = cfname.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
    List<String> TheNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    {

        cfname.moveToFirst();
        while (cfname.moveToNext()) {
            TheNames.add(cfname.getString(GetTheName));

        }
        return TheNames.toArray(new String[TheNames.size()]);
    }

}

}
```

below is the CreateContact class:
    public class CreateContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button Create;
    TextView fname, lname, mobile, address;
    EditText editfirst, editlast, editmobile, editaddress;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createcontact);
    Create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveNewContact);
    fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FirstNametv1);
    lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastNametv1);
    mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Mobiletv1);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Addresstv1);
    editfirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditFirstName);
    editlast = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditLastName);
    editmobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditMobile);
    editaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditAddress);

    Create.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBcreator addition = new DBcreator(CreateContact.this);
    // her you ADD (put) the new data to the SQLite//
    String fname = editfirst.getEditableText().toString();
    String lname = editlast.getEditableText().toString();
    String mob = editmobile.getEditableText().toString();
    String address = editaddress.getEditableText().toString();

    addition.add(fname, lname, mob, address);
    addition.close();
    // go back to the main activity after changes took place//
    Intent k = new Intent(CreateContact.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(k);
}
}
```

below is the EditContact class:

```
public class EditContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button SaveEdit, Cancel, Delete;
TextView fname2, lname2, mobile2, address2;
EditText editfirst2, editlast2, editmobile2, editaddress2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editcontact);
    SaveEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveChanges);
    Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
    Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DeleteContact);
    fname2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FirstNametv2);
    lname2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastNametv2);
    mobile2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Mobiletv2);
    address2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Addresstv2);
    editfirst2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewFirstName);
    editlast2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewLastName);
    editmobile2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewMobile);
    editaddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewAddress);

    SaveEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    Delete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.SaveChanges:
        DBcreator edit = new DBcreator(EditContact.this);
        String fname = editfirst2.getEditableText().toString();
        String lname = editlast2.getEditableText().toString();
        String mob = editmobile2.getEditableText().toString();
        String address = editaddress2.getEditableText().toString();
        edit.savechanges(fname, lname, mob, address);
        edit.close();
        Intent y = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(y);
        break;
    case R.id.CancelButton:
        Intent k = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(k);
        break;
    case R.id.DeleteContact:
        DBcreator delete = new DBcreator(EditContact.this);
        String fnamedelete = editfirst2.getEditableText().toString();
        String lnamedelete = editlast2.getEditableText().toString();
        String mobdelete = editmobile2.getEditableText().toString();
        String addressdelete = editaddress2.getEditableText().toString();
        delete.deletecontact(fnamedelete);
        delete.close();
        Intent h = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(h);
        break;
    }
}

}
```

the logcat

```
12-30 12:08:31.794: E/Trace(11691): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-30 12:08:32.184: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:32.477: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:32.530: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:33.303: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x4f05e390] frames:9, duration:1.000000, fps:8.996834
12-30 12:08:34.680: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:34.719: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x4f05e390] frames:11, duration:1.407000, fps:7.816139
12-30 12:08:34.958: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:35.019: W/MMUMapper(11691): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x526d0000) size(614400) f(0x5)
12-30 12:08:35.020: W/MMUMapper(11691): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x5295d000) size(614400) f(0x5)
12-30 12:08:35.020: W/MMUMapper(11691): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52b00000) size(614400) f(0x5)
12-30 12:08:35.270: W/MMUMapper(11691): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
12-30 12:08:36.274: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.462000, fps:2.734245
12-30 12:08:37.780: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.495000, fps:2.674925
12-30 12:08:38.882: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:3, duration:1.099000, fps:2.729083
12-30 12:08:40.204: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.259000, fps:3.176750
12-30 12:08:41.403: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.267000, fps:3.156914
12-30 12:08:42.486: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.072000, fps:3.729460
12-30 12:08:43.690: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:5, duration:1.215000, fps:4.115116
12-30 12:08:44.736: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.046000, fps:3.823227
12-30 12:08:46.119: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:5, duration:1.379000, fps:3.625341
12-30 12:08:47.287: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.176000, fps:3.399773
12-30 12:08:48.622: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.324000, fps:3.019432
12-30 12:08:49.734: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:5, duration:1.119000, fps:4.465023
12-30 12:08:50.987: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:4, duration:1.155000, fps:3.463197
12-30 12:08:52.023: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11691): [0x529225b8] frames:3, duration:1.140000, fps:2.629971
12-30 12:08:52.226: E/SQLiteLog(11691): (1) near "tablecontactsdisplay": syntax error
12-30 12:08:52.227: W/dalvikvm(11691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416e4908)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablecontactsdisplay": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create tablecontactsdisplay(_idinteger primary key autoincrement,first nameTEXTlast nameTEXTmobileTEXTaddressTEXT);
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at com.hossa.contactsapp.DBcreator.onCreate(DBcreator.java:45)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at com.hossa.contactsapp.DBcreator.add(DBcreator.java:60)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at com.hossa.contactsapp.CreateContact.onClick(CreateContact.java:50)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4093)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17149)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-30 12:08:52.255: E/AndroidRuntime(11691):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 12:08:54.208: I/Process(11691): Sending signal. PID: 11691 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please add the logcat to your question.

Comment: zouzou i put the logcat :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for the help guys i just found out that the classes where implementing another class that i deleted

so i changed this

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);// this orders the code to create the
                            // database//
}
```

to this

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);// this orders the code to create the
                                // database//

}
```

you see my old class was called SQLitedatabase and thus i followed @laalto and @ramaral advice and changed some stuff :)

thx guys

Answer (score 2):

One problem that I can see in or code is the DATABASE_CREATE string. Neead add some spaces and commas between words:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "Create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_MOBILE + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT);";
```

Another problem is the constructor for SQLiteDatabase, it is not declared correctly

```
public SQLiteDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Comment: still same problem bro :(

Comment: i did it and the same occurs

Comment: As @laalto said you must use `yourActivityName.this` when you need a Context in a inner class like OnClickListener

Comment: thx for your help , same problem occurs, please check the new updates...i doubt that there is an error in the creation of the database itself

Comment: See string DATABASE_CREATE in my answer

Comment: Database field names cannot have spaces between words. Change "first name" to "first_name" and "last name" to "last_name"

Comment: i actually changed them but the same error in the logcat occurs 12-30 12:53:26.129: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontactsdisplay": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontactsdisplay(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first_name TEXT NOT NULL, last_name TEXT NOT NULL, mobile TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL);

Comment: Please copy string DATABASE_CREATE from my answer to your code.

Comment: this is how i wrote it and i figured out what was the problem of crashing :) , thx alot @ramaral :)  public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = " CREATE TABLE "
   + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID
   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
   + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MOBILE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

Answer (score 2):

```
12-29 14:02:33.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31505): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hossa.contactsapp.CreateContact$1 cannot be cast to android.content.Context
12-29 14:02:33.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31505):    at com.hossa.contactsapp.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:35)
```

An anonymous inner class `CreateContact$1` is not a `Context`.

You should not trust your IDE's problem solving skills blindly:

```
SQLiteDatabase addition = new SQLiteDatabase(this);
```

Here you are supposed to pass a `Context`. In an `Activity`, passing `this` works but in an `OnClickListener`, this refers to the listner and not the activity. Use `CreateContact.this` to refer to the parent `this` that is a `Context`.

Then, change the parameter you pass to `SQLiteDatabase` constructor to a `Context` and remove the cast here:

```
public SQLiteDatabase(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    super((Context) onClickListener,
```

It's also a good idea to rename the database class as Android already has a class with the same name.

---

Updated: Now you have SQL syntax errors here:

```
Create tablecontactsdisplay(_idinteger primary key autoincrement,first nameTEXTlast nameTEXTmobileTEXTaddressTEXT);
```

You need whitespace between identifiers and keywords, and identifiers either need to have their whitespace removed or the whole identifier quoted. Also there's missing `,` commas. E.g.

```
Create table contactsdisplay(_id integer primary key autoincrement,`first name` TEXT, `last name` TEXT, mobile TEXT, address TEXT);
```

Comment: i did it and the same occurs

Comment: @HossaTheCoder The updated question does not demonstrate that you did so - the `SQLiteDatabase` is still in its broken form. Also as there's likely multiple issues with the code, update the logcat as well in case you hit the next problem.

Comment: thx for your help , same problem occurs, please check the new updates...i doubt that there is an error in the creation of the database itself

Answer (score 0):

You're problem seems to be in this line:
  `SQLiteDatabase addition = new SQLiteDatabase(this);`
In this context `this` refers to instance of onClickListener wich is not instance of context
if you need to refer to instance of activity you should use `CreateContact.this`

Comment: i did it and the same occurs

Answer (score 0):

implement the interface `OnClickListener` instead of using it as " **inner** ", and do the work there.

Instead of this:

```
Create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase addition = new SQLiteDatabase(CreateContact.this);
        // her you ADD (put) the new data to the SQLite//
        String fname = editfirst.getEditableText().toString();
        String lname = editlast.getEditableText().toString();
        String mob = editmobile.getEditableText().toString();
        String address = editaddress.getEditableText().toString();

        addition.add(fname, lname, mob, address);
        addition.close();
        // go back to the main activity after changes took place//
        Intent k = new Intent(CreateContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }
});
```

Do this: `Create.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
public class CreateContact extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

 //etc... etc..

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase addition = new SQLiteDatabase(this);
        // her you ADD (put) the new data to the SQLite//
        String fname = editfirst.getEditableText().toString();
        String lname = editlast.getEditableText().toString();
        String mob = editmobile.getEditableText().toString();
        String address = editaddress.getEditableText().toString();

        addition.add(fname, lname, mob, address);
        addition.close();
        // go back to the main activity after changes took place//
        Intent k = new Intent(CreateContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }

}
```

**Edited**

Your database schema is wrong, the logcat says that there is an syntax error, it should
look like this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE "
                + DATABASE_TABLE + "( "
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT)";
```

You forgot to put a comma to separate every key.

Comment: thx for your help , same problem occurs, please check the new updates...i doubt that there is an error in the creation of the database itself

Comment: thx i noticed this and fixed it and fixed another critical error :)

Comment: Your Welcome, Don't forget to mark it as best answer if it fixed your problems @HossaTheCoder